# How to passing parameter to aws glue workflow using lambda

Tags: aws-glue, aws-data-pipeline, aws-pipeline

I am trying to pass parameter to aws glue workflow using parameter from lambda trigger across all glue jobs in workflow.
How to pass  parameter to glue workflow using lambda

I am able to pass parameter to glue jobs using lambda function but i wanted to pass the same with glue workflow.